# Abelian Group Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order n.

Let $\mathbb{C}^*$ be the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers, and suppose $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism. Prove that $\sum_{g \in G} f(g) = 0$ or $\sum_{g \in G} f(g) = n$.

I can prove this for cyclic groups but am unable to generalise to all abelian groups.

Comment: Without some hypothesis concerning $f$, that is obviously false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, sorry I forgot to add that f is a homomorphism. I've edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is trivial, then $f(g)=1$ for every $g\in G$, hence we get
$$\sum_{g\in G}f(g)=\sum_{g\in G}1=|G|=n$$
Otherwise, let $f(h)\neq 1$ for some $h\in G$.
We have (since $f:G\to\Bbb C^\ast$ is a group homomorphism):
$$f(h)\sum_{g\in G}f(g)=\sum_{g\in G}f(hg)=\sum_{g\in G}f(g)$$
from which
$$(f(h)-1)\sum_{g\in G}f(g)=0$$
hence
$$\sum_{g\in G}f(g)=0$$