# Homomorphism on Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

We are given that $G$ is an abelian group of order $n.$

If $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ is any homomorphism, then show that $\sum_{g \in G} |f(g)| = n$

Please give a hint rather than the answer if possible.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165625/abelian-group-homomorphism) and its answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Given an element $g\in G$, what values could $|f(g)|$ possibly take? (Note that that's absolute value, not algebraic order.)

Comment: Since f(g) has to be nth root of unity, |f(g)| = 1. Hence sum is n. Is this the argument?

Comment: Yep. That's it.

Comment: Other line of reasoning why $|f(g)|=1$ for all $g \in G$: pick $x \in G$ and observe that $\{g:g \in G\}=\{gx: g \in G\}$. Put $\sum_{g \in G}|f(g)|=a$. Then obviously $a \neq 0$. But since $f$ is a homomorphism, $a=\sum_{g \in G}|f(g)|=\sum_{g \in G}|f(gx)|=\sum_{g \in G}|f(g)||f(x)|=|f(x)|\sum_{g \in G}|f(g)|=|f(x)|a$. It follows that $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x \in G$.